# How to manage sessions with PHP and Vue.js?

Tags: php, vue.js, codeigniter, session

**My current scenario:**

My backend was written with PHP (codeigniter) and runs from an Apache server on standard port 80. 
Frontend written with Vuejs (VUE CLI) running from `npm run serve` command in port 8080.

**My problem:**

When I log in to my application, my frontend makes a call to my API endpoint: `http://localhost/auth/login` 
If the authentication data is correct, I start a session with Codeigniter, something like this:

```
 $sessionData = array(
  'username' => $userName,
  'id' => $userId,
  'email' => $userEmail,
  'role' => $userRole,
);
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionData);
```

After that I make a call to retrieve the session data at another API endpoint: http://localhost/get/session

> This is where the problem happens: the call is made from http://localhost:8080 (frontend server) and there is no session open on this path ... PHP ended up opening the session for localhost:80 and that way I can't recover the session data on my frontend.Can someone propose me a solution to solve this problem? I already thought about managing my sessions in a different way but I don't know if it would be a good idea ...

Comment: Why do you run a server for VueJS?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I end up starting the Vue server because if I'm going to use only apache I need to build (npm run build) my application every time I make changes

Comment: For that you can use webpack, grunt, gulp ...

Comment: I've heard of these technologies but I never went very deep, I believe I can start there! :)

Comment: Do you ever, or is it not the practice to use `session_start()` in codeigniter?

Comment: If your front and back ends are on different hosts, you need to make sure your API calls include the [XHR `withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) / [fetch `credentials: "include"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) configuration in order to pass cookies around